# How to do operations between a column and a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I would like to know how I can do operations between a column and a subquery, what I want to do is add to the field `Subtotal` what was obtained in the subquery `Impuestos`, the following is the query that I am using for this case.

```
Select 
RC.PURCHID;
LRC.VALUEMST as 'Subtotal',
                  isnull((
                    select sum((CONVERT(float, TD1.taxvalue)/100)*LRC1.VALUEMST ) as a
                           FROM TAXONITEM TOI1
                           inner join TAXDATA TD1 ON (TD1.TAXCODE = TOI1.TAXCODE and RC.DATAAREAID = TD1.DATAAREAID)
                           inner join TRANS LRC1 on (LRC1.VEND = RC.RECID)
                           WHERE TOI1.TAXITEMGROUP = PL.TAXITEMGROUP and RC.DATAAREAID = TOI1.DATAAREAID 
                    ), 0) Impuestos 
       from VEND RC  
             inner join VENDTABLE VTB on VTB.ACCOUNTNUM = RC.INVOICEACCOUNT
             inner join TRANS LRC on (LRC.VEND = RC.RECID)
             inner join PURCHLINE PL on (PL.LINENUMBER =LRC.LINENUM and PL.PURCHID =RC.PURCHID)
             where year (RC.DELIVERYDATE) =2021 and RC.PURCHASETYPE =3 order by RC.PURCHID;
```

Hope someone can give me some guidance when doing operations with subqueries.

Comment: Just add them? `ColumnName + (sub-query)`.

Answer (score 0):

A few disjointed facts that may help:

- When a `SELECT` statement returns only one row with one column, you can enclose that statement in parenthesis and use it as a plain value. In your case, let's say that `select sum(......= TOI1.DATAAREAID` returns 500. Then, your outer `select`'s second column is equivalent to isnull(500,0)
- You mention in your question "subquery Impuestos". Keep in mind that, although you indeed used a subquery as we mentioned earlier, by the time it was enclosed in parentheses it is not treated as a subquery (more accurately: derived table), but as a value. Thus, the "Impuestos" is only a column alias at this point
- I dislike and avoid subqueries before the `from`, makes things much harder to read. Here is a solution with `apply` which will keep your code mostly intact:

```
    Select 
        RC.PURCHID,
        LRC.VALUEMST as 'Subtotal',
        isnull(subquery1.a, 0) as Impuestos 
    from VEND RC  
         inner join VENDTABLE VTB on VTB.ACCOUNTNUM = RC.INVOICEACCOUNT
         inner join TRANS LRC on (LRC.VEND = RC.RECID)
         inner join PURCHLINE PL on (PL.LINENUMBER =LRC.LINENUM and PL.PURCHID =RC.PURCHID)
         outer apply
         (
            select sum((CONVERT(float, TD1.taxvalue)/100)*LRC1.VALUEMST ) as a
            FROM TAXONITEM TOI1
            inner join TAXDATA TD1 ON (TD1.TAXCODE = TOI1.TAXCODE and RC.DATAAREAID = TD1.DATAAREAID)
            inner join TRANS LRC1 on (LRC1.VEND = RC.RECID)
            WHERE TOI1.TAXITEMGROUP = PL.TAXITEMGROUP and RC.DATAAREAID = TOI1.DATAAREAID 
         ) as subquery1
    where year (RC.DELIVERYDATE) =2021 and RC.PURCHASETYPE =3 order by RC.PURCHID;
```